# ¿Porque tilda el diseño de un control cuando se establece un background image? vb .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

necesito de su ayuda, tengo una imagen (de tipo bitmap) ya establecida a nivel de diseño (visualstudio) en el formulario (winform) en la propiedad `BackgroundImage` y en la propiedad `BackgroundImageLayout = Tile` para que de esta manera lo repita en todo el formulario ahora bien.

En mi `Load`pinto en tiempo de ejecución una serie de controles tipo `PictureBox`pero cuando se ejecuta el programa tilda demasiado por el dibujo de dichos controles.

Pregunta; ¿Habrá alguna forma para que esto no suceda? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Sale algún mensaje o algo? Si no, prueba poniendo `try` `catch` en el código para intentar capturar algo y ver el motivo. Incluso si fuera problema de memoria o procesador saldría un mensaje de error.

Comment: Deberías aportar el código de creación del control `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución a mi problema, lo que pasa es que yo tenía en mi código en el evento Load el siguiente bloque de código:

```
For x = 0 To _numeroSubModulos - 1
            _controlOpcion = New PictureBox
            With _controlOpcion
                .Image = My.Resources.item_menu_banacontrol_white
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
                .Anchor = AnchorStyles.None
                .Name = "Control" & (x + 1).ToString
                .Cursor = Cursors.Hand
                If x < 5 Then
                    .Location = New Point(IIf(_primeraFila = 0, (CInt(_pantalla.Bounds.Width.ToString()) - (IIf(_numeroSubModulos > 5, _numeroSubModulos - (_numeroSubModulos - 5), _numeroSubModulos) * _widthControl) + (IIf(_numeroSubModulos > 5, _numeroSubModulos - (_numeroSubModulos - 5), _numeroSubModulos) * _espacioControles)) / 2, _primeraFila), _controlOpcion.Location.Y)
                    If x = 1 Then _segundaFila = _primeraFila - (_widthControl + _espacioControles)
                    _primeraFila = +_controlOpcion.Location.X + _controlOpcion.Width + _espacioControles
                ElseIf x >= 5 And x < 10 Then
                    .Location = New Point(_segundaFila, _controlOpcion.Height + _espacioControles)
                    If x = 6 Then _terceraFila = _segundaFila - (_widthControl + _espacioControles)
                    _segundaFila = _segundaFila + _controlOpcion.Width + _espacioControles
                ElseIf x >= 10 And x < 15 Then
                    .Location = New Point(_terceraFila, (_controlOpcion.Height + _espacioControles) * 2)
                    _terceraFila = _terceraFila + _controlOpcion.Width + _espacioControles
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            End With
            pnl_contenedor.Controls.Add(_controlOpcion)
        Next
```

Y lo que hacía era que al dibujar un control le asignaba la imagen y eso provocaba que por cada iteración y dibujo de control, existiera esa pequeña latencia.

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
 If DesignMode Then
    Return
 End If
 BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf OnMainFormLoaded))
```

Para que el aplicativo sepa que mi formulario no esta en modo diseño si no hasta que termina la carga de el método que estoy llamando en el load.

Gracias, espero que a alguien le sirva.

Comment: recuerda volver en 24 horas y aceptar esta respuesta!